# How to get e-mail notification of successful backup jobs with DPM 2010?

Tags: backup, email, scdpm

I'm testing Microsoft System Center Data Protection Manager 2010, and I don't seem to be able to find something that I think *should* be there: have it send e-mail notifications for *successful* backup jobs.

I've configured e-mail notifications, and I've enabled them at all levels (information, warning, critical), yet they are only sent when something goes wrong, like a job failing; nothing is ever sent when a backup job goes right, be it an incremental or a full one.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious... but I searched everywhere, and I couldn't find any setting for configuring this.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, looks like there is ***no way*** to achieve this with DPM 2010, other than horrible kludges like using SQL Server triggers combined with SQL Mail (let's not dwell into this, there lies madness).

I hope this gets added in the future... that really is a missing feature in an otherwise very good product.